# how to use the global timer for all the javascript animation in page

Tags: javascript, animation

In my page,there are several animations(change size or backgroundColor using the timer),I heard that using too many timer in one page will cause performance problem,and using the global timer is recommended.

But the animation are not started in the same time.

For example,I have two element(ele1 and ele2) whose width will be changed per second.

And there is the glboal timer.

```
var timer=setInterval(animation,?);

function animation(){
  //do ele1's animation
  //do ele2's animation
}
```

At 0s,user trigger animation of ele1,and at 0.5s user trigger ele2.

Now,how to set the delay of the globle timer?

1s?

If so,at 1s,the width of the ele2 will be changed but  at 1.5s,the timer should do something for ele2 because the ele2's animaation is trigged at .5s,however the next occur of the timer will be 2s,then how to fix it?

And idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use global timer with [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of all timers.

If you have timer for 1.0 and 1.5, you can create global timer for 0.5 and maintain one global variable for number of times global timer is called.

```
var timerCount = 0 ;
var timer=setInterval(animation,500);

function animation(){

    // i.e. ele1TimerValue / globalTimerValue
    if(timerCount%2) {
        //do ele1's animation
    }

    if(timerCount%3) {  
        //do ele2's animation
    }
    ++timerCount;
}
```

For many animations, it will be better to use this timer as controller for calling respective animations (like `ele1Animate()` and `ele2Animate()`).

Comment: but the count of the animations in the page is not sure ,the same with there delay.

Comment: @hguser That is what I am saying if there are multiple timers you have to take GCD of all of them. For `1, 1.5, 2.5, 5` it will be `0.5`. Then use global timer with that value. As number will be multiple of GCD you can write then in this format.

Comment: but I have to initialize the timer at the first animation started,at this time,I do not know how many animations at the page.

Comment: @hguser Then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698866/global-timer-in-javascript-with-multiple-callbacks) might be what you are looking for