# Auto call function in durandaljs or knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, momentjs, durandal-2.0

I have an app which displays the activity relative time using moment js plugin. The time is refreshed automatically comparing it with current time and displays (like facebook newsfeed). App was previously written in angularjs where i built this functionality with following code:
**JS:**

```
filter('convertSeconds', function() {
        return function(seconds) {
            if( typeof(seconds) == 'undefined' ) return;
            // units is a string with possible values of y, M, w, d, h, m, s, ms
            var duration = moment.utc().subtract(seconds, 'seconds'), format = "";

            if( duration.day() > 0 ) { format += "DD [days] "; }

            if(duration.hour() > 0){ format += "H [hours] "; }

            if(duration.minute() > 0){ format += "m [minutes] "; }

            format += " s [seconds]";

            return duration.fromNow(true);
        }
    }).
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="time-spent">
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o mrs fa-2"></i>
   {{me.current.activity.time_spent|convertSeconds}}
</div>
```

The angularjs filters are called automatically every second therefore time is refreshed and i dont have to take care of that.

Now the app is being rewritten and js framework shifts from angularjs to durandaljs (on clients requirement) i dont know how can i achieve same thing with durandaljs.

Comment: Angular app became durandal app, this is interesting..

Comment: Could `Activity` itself be a view?  You speak of an "array of activities" in one of your comments.  Are activities merely object literals with a few properties, or something more formal?  The question revolves a little bit around architecture.  Are we building a generic *relative timer*, or specifically an *activity relative timer*?  Also, you might want to consider the global timer approach when developing that module.  See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2698866/3174746.

Comment: @EricTaylor The purpose of application is to track the time spent on activities by different persons, so i have a list of activities and each activity has its properties. I need specifically an activity relative timer because user can also pause and resume the timer

Answer (score 1):

Views in durandal have a [life cycle](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks) so you can use events to start(when the view is activated) and stop(when the view is deactivated) a javascript timer. Add a ko observable called time_spent_trigger to your model.  Add another ko computed observable called time_spent_formatted that does all your moment calculations and returns the final result but at the top, make it reference the time_spent_trigger in some way.  In your view, bind to the time_spent_formatted property instead of the time_spent property.  In the activate event, start a timer that updates the time_spent_trigger every second.  In the deactivate event, cancel this timer.  updating the value for the time_spent_trigger will cause the computed observable to change and be updated on the view.

JS:

```
define([
    'durandal/system',
    'knockout'
    ],
    function (system, ko) {
        var vm = {
            time_spent = ko.observable(),
            time_spent_trigger = ko.observable(0),
            activate: activate,
            deactivate: deactivate,
            updateTimerId = 0
        };

        vm.time_spent_formatted = ko.computed(function () {
          //reference the trigger observable in some way
          if (vm.time_spent_trigger() > 0)
          {
              //do your moment calculation and return here
              return result_of_moment_calculation
          } else {
              return "Not Started";
          }
        }

        return vm;

        function activate() {

            vm.updateTimerId = setInterval(function () {
                vm.time_spent_trigger(vm.time_spent_trigger() + 1);
            }, 10000);

        }

        function deactivate() {
            clearInterval(vm.updateTimerId);
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="time-spent">
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o mrs fa-2"></i>
  <span data-bind="text: time_spent_formatted"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This view will leak.  You need to add a `detached` handler, also part of the view lifecycle, with the following line: `vm.time_spent_formatted.dispose()`.  Unless you use the new `pureComputed`, if indeed it can be used, you must dispose of your computeds.

Comment: @EricTaylor interesting, didn't realize that, so would I still need to do the dispose if this was not a singleton (instead of returning vm, return a function for creating a vm object)?

Comment: Even more so in the non-singleton case.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically need a relative timer, right?

We need someone to tell us what current time is.

```
//clock.js    
define(function (require) {
    var
        events = require('durandal/events'),
        moment = require('moment'),
        clock = {};

    events.includeIn(clock);

    setInterval(function () {
        clock.trigger('time:changed', moment());
    }, 1000);

    return clock;
});
```

How here is your relative timer that uses clock events.

```
//timer.js
define(function (require) {
    var
        ko = require('knockout'),
        moment = require('moment'),
        startTime = ko.observable(null),
        relativeTime = ko.observable(),

        start = function () {
            startTime(moment());
        },
        stop = function () {
            startTime(null);
        },
        clock = require('clock');

    clock.on('time:changed').then(function (time) {
        startTime() && relativeTime(moment.duration(time, startTime()).humanize());
    });

    return {
        relativeTime: relativeTime, //use data-bind="text: relativeTime"
        start: start,
        stop: stop
    }

});
```

Comment: Actually i have an array of activities which are running so i have to update time_spent property of every index in array how can i do that. I am new to durandal.

Comment: Then you can just make timer.js a factory and create one instance for every item in your array.